# Использовать exec или избегать?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py, exec

Пишу discord бота на питоне. Хотелось бы вынести каждую команду в отдельный файл.
Единственное что я придумал - читать содержимое файла и использовать функцию exec.
Использовать import не получится, так как в коде команд используются глобальные переменные.

Уместно ли такое решение, или есть варианты получше?
Недаром ведь говорят "eval is evil" :)

(код подаю в сокращенном и обрезанном виде, оставил только элементы по сути вопроса)

```
bot=Bot()

@bot.command()
async def command1(ctx):
    await ctx.send("command1 invoked")

@bot.command()
async def command2(ctx):
    await ctx.send("bot is on %s guilds"%len(bot.guilds))
```

Comment: Как глобальные переменные мешают импортам?

Comment: если вынести функцию в отдельный файл, она не будет видеть переменную bot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел оптимальный для меня вариант.

**helper_lib.py**

```
#импорты библиотек и объявления функций
```

**bot_commands/command1.py**

```
from helper_lib import *

@bot.command()
async def command1(ctx):
   await ctx.send("command1")
```

**bot.py**

```
import helper_lib

bot=Bot()

helper_lib.bot=bot
#другие глобальные переменные

from bot_commands import command1
```

Вроде получилось нормально, комментируйте если что.

Answer (score 0):

Вариант №1, если хочется чтобы декораторы выглядели именно как декораторы

В отдельных файлах заворачиваете ваши функции так:

```
def make_command1(bot):

    @bot.command()
    async def command1(ctx):
        await ctx.send("command1 invoked")
```

В главном файле используете их так:

```
from command1_file import make_command1


bot = Bot()

command1 = make_command1(bot)
```

Вариант №2

В отдельных файлах пишите только функции без декораторов:

```
async def command1(ctx):
    await ctx.send("command1 invoked")
```

А в главном файле привязываете их к боту так:

```
from command1_file import command1


bot = Bot()

command1 = bot.command()(command1)
```

Вариант 3, модификация варианта 1. Если вам так уж хочется иметь доступ к глобальным переменным не передавая их явно.

Вот так в отдельном файле:

```
def make_command1():
    
    bot = globals()['bot']

    @bot.command()
    async def command1(ctx):
        await ctx.send("command1 invoked")
```

Вот так в главном:

```
from command1_file import make_command1


bot = Bot()

command1 = make_command1()
```

Но я крайне не рекомендую так делать, лучше все переменные передавать явно. В данном варианте вам самостоятельно придётся следить за тем, чтобы все нужные глобальные переменные были объявлены строго до строчек `command1 = make_command1()`

Comment: вариант 2 не подходит, так как bot используется также в теле функций, вариант 1  тоже не очень потому что bot это не единственная глобальная переменная, которая используется в функциях

Comment: В варианте 1 вы можете точно так же через аргументы передавать весь набор нужных переменных.

Comment: Я добавил третий вариант в мой ответ

Answer (score 0):

Используйте Cogs: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/cogs.html

```py
# mycog.py
from discord.ext import commands

class MyCog(commands.Cog):
    """My awesome cog"""  # будет показываться в !help MyCog

    def __init__(self, bot: commands.Bot):  
        # можно обойтись и без ссылки на объект бота в классе, 
        # но в таком случае объект бота придётся доставать через ctx.bot
        self.bot = bot

    @commands.command()
    async def cmd(self, ctx):
        await ctx.send("invoked cmd")
```

```py
# main.py
from mycog import MyCog

bot = commands.Bot()
bot.add_cog(MyCog(bot))  # добавить "модуль"
# bot.remove_cog("MyCog")  # убрать "модуль"
```